# How to create DOM element with click handler in one go?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an element on the fly, like this way:

```
var productItemTop = $(
  "<span>" +
    "<a class='spamItemsX' href='#' " +
    "onclick=" +
    eval(launchGenericProductSearch(topProducts)) +
    ">" +
    topProducts +
    "</a>" +
    "</span>"
);
```

But every time I load the page, the function `launchGenericProductSearch` is get called, but I don't want it to be called then, but when the link is clicked.

Comment: If this is part of your initial Load, then yes, the function would get called each time the page loads. It's not clear what you did want to have happen. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example This example cannot be replicated.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve here.  It seems like you could achieve what you're trying to do in other ways, perhaps by just adding an event listener on the document for the selector `.spamItemsX` that does what you need, perhaps taking `topProducts` from some attribute of the target.

Comment: Each time the browser is reloaded, all the JavaScript in the page will reruns. If you want to call it on demand, you can declare it in a function and call it later.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `launchGenericProductSearch` will be executed immediately, not when the user clicks.

You will get better control over your code when you use jQuery to the full, avoid `eval`, and bind click handlers not via HTML, but via JS (jQuery) code:

```
var productItemTop = $("<span>").append(
    $("<a>").addClass('spamItemsX')
           .attr("href", '#')
           .click(() => launchGenericProductSearch(topProducts))
           .text(topProducts)
    );
```

Comment: You mean this way  var productItemTop = $("<span>")
              .append("<a>")
              .addClass("spamItemsX")
              .attr("href", "#")
              .click(() => launchGenericProductSearch(topProducts))
              .text(topProducts);

            spanItemsTop.appendTo(divItemsTop);
            productItemTop.appendTo(divItemsTop);
            // }
          }); because I tried with your code and did not work

Comment: Is there anything different? Except for the other code you added (which was not in your question)? Of course, I don't know what `launchGenericProductSearch` is, and what the rest of your code is. There can be many things that are not working. I only vouch for the part I put in my answer. It will not execute `launchGenericProductSearch` immediately, like was your problem.

Comment: sorry. your code has an extra final parenthesis and in console shows that "<a>".addClass is not a function

Comment: Yes, fixed that.